# Geometric intuition of linear transformations with complex eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, linear-transformations

I am trying to gain a fine intuition in regards to how space is transformed under iteration of a matrix with purely complex, or mixed real/complex eigenvalues.  In particular, I have the following questions.

**(1)** If a matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ has a real eigenvalue $\lambda$, and $|\lambda|>1$ is greater in magnitude than all other eigenvalues, then space will be "stretched out" over the eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$ as $A$ is applied to the space.  Now, what happens if $A$ has real eigenvector $\lambda$ and complex eigenvalue pair $\mu, \bar{\mu}$, such that $|\mu|=|\bar{\mu}| > |\lambda|$ and $1$. In this case, does space still get stretched out over the eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$, or does the rotational/scaling component from the $\mu$ eigenvectors take over?

**(2)** If the eigenvalues of a matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ are all complex (have nonzero complex component), but the coefficients are all rational, then given a $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$, does there exist a $k \geq 1$ such that $A^kv \in \text{span}(v)$?

**(3)** Suppose now $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ has only complex eigenvalues and eigenvectors.  Then if I am not mistaken, the eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalues $\mu, \bar{\mu}$ are orthogonal.  But then if $\mu, \bar{\mu}$ have modulus strictly greater than the other eigenvectors, and greater than 1, how is space transformed here, as there does not appear to be a line that space gets "stretched out" over because the eigenvalues are orthogonal.